# Sending big amounts of data from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, compression

I am searching for a method to ship about 5MB of data from my PHP server to JavaScript/jQuery. Currently, I am sending plain text of database records, but the problem is, I am sending it every x amount of time per x amount of settings, and it makes the application slow.

Would there be a way to hash/compress the output, then decompress it in JavaScript/jQuery so it's not sending as much across everytime?

Comment: Without knowing the purpose of the data it's hard to advise you. What is it used for? Can you not cache on the client and only send changes on each update?

Comment: Do you know which part is slow? Gzip, for example, could speed up the network transfer, but it won't speed up the JavaScript that has to parse or process your data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your reply, I am sending JSON to my JavaScript which puts it in a table. So, that might be possible, but I am not entirely sure how.

Comment: @joews Thanks for your reply, the network transfer is a bit slow. When I have a look into my network tab in Chrome, it says 5MB and then xxx amount of time which slows everything down quite a lot.

Comment: Ensure your server has HTTP compression on. Compression is a transport/network job not the concern of the end point applications.

Comment: 5Mb of plain text data is a lot to show in a single table. I would suggest you look in to pagination or lazy loading.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My table already has pagination, but I still need to send all the data to the table.

Comment: I am using gzip which compresses it quite a lot, thanks everyone!

Comment: Why are you sending all data to a paginated table? The whole point of pagination is to only send the required chunk of data for each page to reduce bandwidth and page rendering time...?

Comment: The DataTables plugin requires all data, then they create pages from it.